# <script>Not Getting Lat and Long from the given map address jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I want to find lat and lng from given address but i cant find same can you please help me to solve this query

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
 var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "patan"}, function(results, status) {
    alert(status)
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      alert(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
        //$('.push-down').text("location : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " +results[0].geometry.location.lng()); 
      } else {
        $('.push-down').text("Something got wrong " + status);
      }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Kindly try below code :-

```html
<div class="push-down"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script>
 var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "patan"}, function(results, status) {
    //alert(status)
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var Lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var Lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
       $('.push-down').html("latitude: " + Lat + " <br/>longitude:  " +Lng); 
      } else {
        $('.push-down').text("Something got wrong " + status);
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: gives same error TypeError: e.easing.easeOutCubic is not a function

Comment: @jigneshprajapati  lol:). same code, so same error. did you saw any change in this code than mine. Don't say that you saw any changes

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is marked php as well, I would recommend using the [Google Geocode API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). I find it much easier to use, than the js API.

Here is an example code:

```
<?php

//  Request URL for Google Geocode API, result type = json, language = hu-HU, region = hu-HU
//  Change result type, language, region to your needs
define('REQ_URL', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=hu&region=hu');
//  Your Google API key goes here
define('API_KEY', 'your-google-api-key-goes-here');

//  Address you want to geocode
//  Needs to be url encoded
$address = 'address-you-want-to-geocode-goes-here';
$address = urlencode($address);

//  Parsing full request url
$request_url = REQ_URL . '&address=' . $address . '&key=' . API_KEY;

//  Query Google API for result
$response = file_get_contents($request_url);
$resp = json_decode($response, true);

//  Result array
print '<pre>';
print_r($resp);
print '</pre>';
```

I hope, I could be of any help.